# How can I conditional show a Custom Taxonomy in Wordpress only after a particular category is Selected?

Tags: wordpress, post, types, taxonomy

I have a video website. and all the posts have an embedded video.

So I want to achieve the following. In WordPress by default we have "Category" & "tags" I have these categories to select from
'Movie Reviews' 
'Song Reviews'
'Lyrics Review'

Then I create the following custom taxonomies "Actors" "Singers" "Writers"

The problem: When ever I create a new post I see all 5 tacomomies for every post "category" "tags" "Actors" "Singers" "Writers"

This is what I want. I should only see categories & tags. But once I select a specific category and publish the related custom taxonomy should be Displayed. For example if i publish post with 'Movie Review' category it should display "Actors".

---

I know Alternative solution is to create new custom post types for movies, songs & lyrics and use custom taxonomies with them but I wan to achieve it with categories.

Comment: I have not yet tried anything. Note sure where to start

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get a better idea of how to ask a question here